# Need help on if test condition

Tags: linux, bash

Need your help on below script where I am testing if file found at location /log/TestFile* and id there is only one file then it will display "File successfully Found" else "note found". my second condition - [ $sfCount == 1 ]; is not working. please help me with that.

```
sfCount=`ls -l /log/TestFile* | awk '{print $9}'| wc -l |sed "s/[[:blank:]]//g" | sed '/^$/d' | sed 's/\n//g'`
sFile=`ls -l /log/TestFile* | awk '{print $9}'`

if [ -e /log/$sFile ] && [ $sfCount == 1 ]; then
    echo "File successfully Found"
    exit 0
else 
    echo "File Not found"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Try adding `echo "<$sfCount>"` to see what really is in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have to correct above and its working fine

```
----------------- Script start here ------------------------- 
sfCount=ls -l /log/TestFile* | awk '{print $9}'| wc -l |sed "s/[[:blank:]]//g" | sed '/^$/d' | sed 's/\n//g' 
sFile="TestFile*"

if [ -f $IB_DIR/$sFile ] && [ $sfCount == 1 ]; then
    echo "File successfully Found"
    exit 0
else 
    echo "File Not found"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Its not clear to me if you added information to your question or if you answered your own question. I think you answered your own question, and that's OK (see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)). In this case, you should accept your own answer to make it clear to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file count much more easily by doing the following:

```
ls /log/TestFile* | wc -l
```

That will relieve you of all the other.
I'm not sure why you are getting a count of the number of files, and also putting them into an array to see if they exist. From what it looks like, you just want to see **if** they exist. You only need the first command for that. So, what we are left with is:

```
if [ $(ls /log/TestFile* 2>/dev/null | wc -l) != 0 ]; then
    echo "File Found"
else 
    echo "File not found"
fi
```

The "2>/dev/null" will suppress output to STDERR if there are no files found. We simply want 0, or not 0.